# $\{x \in \mathbb{R^2} : x_1x_2=1\}$ - Compact

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Let A = $\{x \in \mathbb{R^2} :  x_1x_2=1\}$.

I try to show that this set in not compact. If I find a sequence for which there is not convergente subsequence, then it will be proved. 
For the realization, I will use the contrapositive of the Cauchy theorem.

Is anyone could give me a such sequence?

Comment: It  is not bounded. But if you want no convergent subsequence let $x_1=1,2,3,4,\dots$.

Comment: HINT: Show instead that the set is unbounded.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to produce a sequence with no convergent subsequence, let $x_1=1,2,3,4,\dots$.

Comment: Does A is itself a sequence?

Comment: $A$ is not a sequence. The sequence I described briefly in the answer is the sequence $(p_n)$ of points where $p_n=(n,1/n)$. It is not hard to show this has no convergent subsequence, but it does take some writing. If you already know the theorem that a set in Euclidean space is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded, then you can prove $A$ is not compact  in one short line.

Answer (score 1):

You note that the graph of the function $y=\dfrac{1}{x}$ is  unboundend. For the Heine Borel Theorem a subset of the euclidean plane is compact iff it's closed and bounded.

Comment: It's worth noting this just being the graph $y=f(x)$ of a function $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ can't be compact - a bounded function is just as problematic as an unbounded one. So here we get trouble on both fronts, having an unbounded domain and an unbounded range.

Comment: This depends on the metric (of course, I know you mean the standard Euclidean metric). However, "complete and totally bounded" is a better way to characterize compactness in the metric setting. For example, you could use the standard bounded metric given by $\hat{d}(x,y) = \min(d(x,y),1)$; this gives the same "small" open balls, so the same topology, but every set is "bounded" regardless of whether it is compact. "Totally bounded" removes this obstacle.

Answer (score 1):

This set is the graph of the curve $y=1/x$, which is a hyperbola. You should realize that, for example, the sequence $\{ (n,1/n): n\in\mathbb N\}$ lies on this curve but does not contain a convergent subsequence.